# about anti-symmetric rank 3 tensor

Tags: tensors

[image: Problem 3]

I am trying to prove that $\epsilon_{ijk}$$\epsilon_{lmn}$ equals to the determinant on the right. I calculated the determinant and write out all the non-zero sum of $\epsilon_{ijk}$, but then I don't know what to do next. I am also confused about what $\epsilon_{ijk}$$\epsilon_{lmn}$ means. I thought it was a summation, but other people pointed out that it isn't. So if anyone can explain it with simple concepts would be appreciated.

note: $\epsilon$ is the anti-symmetric rank 3 tensor and $\delta$ is the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta)

Comment: That last one isn't true, you can only sum when an index is repeated

Comment: I am sorry. Can you elaborate more? From start, can you tell me what $\epsilon_{ijk}$ means?

Comment: That tensor is known as the Levi-Civita tensor (sometimes pseudotensor). Also known as the permutation symbol https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol. You might also want to look up either Einstein summation convention or Ricci calculus

Comment: The other symbol is the Kronecker Delta, it functions as the identity tensor